# How to populate arry json

Tags: java, json

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {

            jsonObjectRow = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
            name = jsonObjectRow.get("tag").toString();
            size = jsonObjectRow.get("size").toString();
           ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            arrStre[i] = (JSONArray) jsonObjectRow.get("street"); // popola solo ultimo


            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            tag[i] = "tag" + name;
            sizes[i] = "size" + size;
        }
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at inpserver.Parser.MemoDati.popolamento(MemoDati.java:48)
>       at TestingMain.MainTest.main(MainTest.java:11)
>   C:\Users\norberto\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\debug.xml:83: Java returned: 1
>   BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

the error is in line arrSTre[i]... etc.
why NullPointerException?

Comment: you probably didn't initialize `arrStre`

Comment: `jsonObjectRow` may be null as well